# CSS transform rotation mozilla

Tags: css, animation

can anyone tell me as to why this declaration does not work in Mozilla. In Chrome and safari it works great.

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
    from{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);

    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

.rotating {
    -webkit-animation: rotating 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: rotating 10s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: rotating 10s linear infinite;
    animation: rotating 10s linear infinite;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should apply

```
@-moz-keyframes rotating {
    from{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);

    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
```

You should apply prefixes for keyframes

Comment: I don't think you need the -webkit and -o prefixes when you're just targeting Firefox though in the stages of animation

Comment: Thank you, i missed that. Much appreciated